# Using HMS AREngine to do image tracking, it keeps giving ACameraMetadata error

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to develop a tool to do image tracking using HMS AREngine, the basic idea is firstly setting up ARAugmentedImageDatabase, opening the source image as Bitmap for image recognition from drawable folder, then adding the Bitmap to Database using addImage()

```
arAugmentedImageDatabase = new ARAugmentedImageDatabase(arSession);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.img_one);
arAugmentedImageDatabase.addImage("cup",bitmap);
```

But this code keeps giving error:

```
E/ACameraMetadata: getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag 1114118
E/ACameraMetadata: getConstEntry: cannot find metadata tag -2147483139
```

The image file I used is in jpg format, I also tried to put the file in Assets folder but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening the source image as **InputStream** from the Assets folder, then call the **decodeStream** method to transform it as Bitmap. Also please be aware to set up the Database during activity's **onResume** state.

Here's the sample code you can refer to:

```
arAugmentedImageDatabase = new ARAugmentedImageDatabase(arSession);
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("img_one.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
arAugmentedImageDatabase.addImage("cup",bitmap);
```

Comment: That works :) But there is a short black screen time before the camera starts, is that because of the image size?